# Github latest release is not same as a newest release

Tags: github

[image]

This is the situation.

1. **30 minutes ago**, I made a release note with tag name `v4.2.4`
2. then, **just now** I make a new release note with tag name `2022-07-18-0013` (this tag name is just about date, my company sometime
   use this style version)

As far as I know latest release meaning that the newest release note, But In my case only semantic version(v4.2.4) can have `latest` tag.

why this is happened?
I can not find any rules about only semantic version has privilege to get a latest.

(I want to know why this is happened, because I use latest release [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#get-the-latest-release))

#### ------------- EDIT ----------------

`git log --oneline` print result below

```
0bc82b8 Merge pull request #166 from devstefancho/feature/0718_test1
2e85d9a add
6cc313e add
4c7e5b2 Merge pull request #165 from devstefancho/feature/0717_test2
f018fca test
b403615 Merge pull request #163 from devstefancho/feature/0717_test2
e7dd66f test
```

`git log --graph --oneline`

```
*   0bc82b8 Merge pull request #166 from devstefancho/feature/0718_test1
|\  
| * 2e85d9a add
|/  
* 6cc313e add
*   4c7e5b2 Merge pull request #165 from devstefancho/feature/0717_test2
|\  
| * f018fca test
* | b403615 Merge pull request #163 from devstefancho/feature/0717_test2
|\| 
| * e7dd66f test
|/
```

#### ------------------- Solved --------------------

Thanks for the great answer, finally figure out!

Reason : same day timestamp

If tags are not created in a same day, then the newest(by time) tag will be `latest` tag

[image]

Comment: what is the relation between commit b403 and 4c7e? maybe the former is newer than the latter?

Comment: @criztovyl I add git log list, b403 is older than 4c7e

Comment: what does `git log --graph --oneline` say?

Comment: @criztovyl okay, I also add git log graph in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information was [provided by a GitHub staff member](https://github.community/t/release-page-not-sorting-correctly/121002/2):

> Releases are based on Git tags, which mark a specific point in your repository’s history. The sort order of tags is as follows:
>
> - Tags are sorted by the timestamp of the underlying commit that they point to
> - If those commits are created on the same day, then the sorting is based on Semantic Versioning of the name of the tag (https://semver.org/)
> - If the Semantic Versioning is the same, they are sorted by second of creation
>
> Pre-release versions have a lower precedence than the associated normal version.

Comment: thanks! then I need to test another day to avoid same day, after testing I would like to select your answer.

Comment: @devstefancho Sounds good. Please let us know if the results of your testing confirm the information.

Comment: it finally turns out, the reason is the same day timestamp.
like your second information, if tags are created in same day. then "latest" green tag is given to the most recent semantic version tag. if tags are not created in same day. then "latest" green tag will be given to the newest tag

Comment: I added final result screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it is still strange my same-day release `v0.1.1-beta1` gets higher than `v0.1.1` (though `v0.1.1` is marked as the Latest).

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I guess their sorting algorithm thinks `v0.1.1-beta1` > `v0.1.1`